# Is `if (idx < arr.length)` equivalent to `if (arr[idx])`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

Assuming that all elements inside an array have a value different from `undefined`, `null` or `0`, is

`if (idx < arr.length)` equivalent to `if (arr[idx])`?

Comment: It would work as long as there are no falsely values.

Comment: all elements inside you array are not  a boolean value === false ?

Comment: not the same: what if `idx` is negative? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

There are other [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values that will evaluate to `false` in the `if` statement, such as an empty string (`''`):

```js
const arrWithEmptyString = ['', '', ''];
const idx = 2;

console.log(!!(idx < arrWithEmptyString.length));
console.log(!!arrWithEmptyString[idx]);
```

Alternatively, what if the array contains a boolean `false`?

```js
const boolArray = [true, false, true, false]
const idx = 3;
console.log(!!(idx < boolArray.length));
console.log(!!boolArray[idx]);
```

[Type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion)/[type conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_Conversion) in JS can be confusing and unpredictable-- in my opinion it is generally better to be explicit and test exactly what it is you mean to test, rather than relying on weak type comparisons to save a few characters.

Comment: I see, there a more values that evaluate to false that I didn't think of. But what if the values inside the array don't evaluate to false? Would it be possible to check if the element at `idx` is inside the array using `if (arr[idx])` in this case? Is that hard to read or a bad style?

Comment: You can see my update-- there are a few places where you can rely on automatic type conversion/coercion to be clever, but _generally_ I'd recommend being explicit and testing exactly what it is you are trying to evaluate, for better readability and lower chance of unexpected/buggy behavior.  If you simply want to know if the value at the index is falsy, then by all means use `array[idx]`-- but if you want to know if it is inbounds in the array, using a `.length` check is more semantically accurate and consistent with what you are actually trying to evaluate.

Comment: I want to check if the element at `array[idx]` exists. Usually I check if `something` exists by writing `if (something)`. But I also know, if the index is within the length of the array, the element does exist. So it's hard to tell what is more semantically accurate.

Comment: Yes, sounds like you have a somewhat ambiguous situation on your hands.  I suppose if you're merely checking for existence, and you're confident you won't have falsy values, an existence check is the right way to go.  You could always make it more specific and include guardrails against falsiness.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Nice answer from Alexander Nied, also NaN evaluates to false

```
const boolArray = [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]
const idx = 3;
console.log(!!(idx < boolArray.length));
console.log(!!boolArray[idx]);
```